# Run a specific unittest with loadTestsFromName

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to run a single test and output the result to a txt file. I understood that I can use `loadTestsFromName` to specify the test. However, I'm getting an error.

test.py

```
import unittest
import sys
import os

def main(out=sys.stderr, verbosity=2):
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromName(sys.modules[__name__]=='test1')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(out, verbosity=verbosity).run(suite)


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('test-results.txt', 'w') as f:
        main(f)
```

I run the test by executing `python test.py`

I'm not sure how to get `test1`. I tried `sys.modules[__name__]=='test1'` but it triggered this error.

```
parts = name.split('.')
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [python doc-unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromName](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromName), below code is work for me.

```py
import unittest
import sys
import os


def main(out=sys.stderr, verbosity=2):
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromName('__main__.TestClass.test1')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(out, verbosity=verbosity).run(suite)


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('test-results.txt', 'w') as f:
        main(f)
```

Besides, you'd better separate the `TestCase` to the single module, then change the `__main__` to the module name.